# Redshift Copy Command Errors: could not open relation with OID 591923 through AWS Glue Spark

Tags: sql, apache-spark, amazon-redshift, aws-glue

There is a code which has been running since 6 months in production, which runs in a loop for given number of tables and does a redshift copy. It is has been running successfully till 31st October, from 1st November till date it failed (for one particular table; runs fine for others).

```
## Truncate and execute Copy command.
def ExecuteCopyCommand(TableList): 
    
    QueryIdDict = {}
    for TableName in TableList:
        SourcePath = f's3://{BucketName}/{prefix}'  
        query = f" truncate table {TableName}; \
                    copy {TableName} \
                    from '{SourcePath}' \
                    iam_role 'abcd' \
                    delimiter as '.' \
                    ignoreheader 1 \
                    dateformat as 'auto' \
                    timeformat as 'auto' \
                    Null as 'NULL';"
        
        ## Executing truncate and copy command on redshift cluster
        try: 
            response = client.execute_statement(
                ClusterIdentifier='redshift-abc',
                Database='abc',
                SecretArn='arn:aws:secretsmanager:abcd',
                Sql= query
    
            )
            print(TableName + ": Copy command executed")
            print('Query',query)
            print('Response',response)
            QueryId = response['Id']
            QueryIdDict[QueryId] = TableName
            DataDict= { 'Level': 'Info',
                        'SourceLocation': SourcePath,
                        'TargetDatabaseName': 'redshift-abc',
                        'TargetSchemaName': str(TableName.split('.')[0]),
                        'TargetTableName': str(TableName.split('.')[1]),
                        'ExecutedQuery': query.strip(),
                        'ExecutedQueryId': str(QueryId),
                        'Description': 'Copy command executed on redshift and query is in progress.',
                        'Status': 'Succeeded' 
                       }
            DataList.append(DataDict)
            time.sleep(1)
        except Exception as e:
            DataDict= { 'Level': 'Error',
                        'SourceLocation': SourcePath,
                        'TargetDatabaseName': 'redshift-abc',
                        'TargetSchemaName': str(TableName.split('.')[0]),
                        'TargetTableName': str(TableName.split('.')[1]),
                        'ExecutedQuery': query.strip(),
                        'ExecutedQueryId': '',
                        'Description': f'Fail to execute copy command. Error : {str(e)}',
                        'Status': 'Failed' 
                      }
            DataList.append(DataDict)
            print('Error occur in  ExecuteCopyCommand block.')
            print('Error occur while executing copy command.')
            print('TableName : ' +  TableName)
            print(e)
            raise
    print('Query dict',QueryIdDict)        
    return QueryIdDict
```

The below code fails with the following error:

Main error: `Exception: ERROR: could not open relation with OID 591927`

Traceback:

```
test_table: Copy command executed
Query  truncate table test_table;                     copy test_table                     from 's3://bucket_test/pipeline/test_table/year=2022/month=02/day=28/'                     iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::xyz:role/Account-B-Glue-Redshift-Cloudwatch'                     delimiter as '.'                     ignoreheader 1                     dateformat as 'auto'                     timeformat as 'auto'                     Null as 'NULL';
Response {'ClusterIdentifier': 'redshift-abc', 'CreatedAt': datetime.datetime(2022, 11, 10, 6, 21, 42, 363000, tzinfo=tzlocal()), 'Database': 'abc', 'Id': 'abcdcs-4878-446b-80e9-8d544860847a', 'SecretArn': 'arn:aws:secretsmanager:abcd', 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': '690f6542-4e33-4d84-afb8-2f9ebc9af62e', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid': '690f6542-4e33-4d84-afb8-2f9ebc9af62e', 'content-type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.1', 'content-length': '231', 'date': 'Thu, 10 Nov 2022 06:21:42 GMT'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}
Query dict {'abcdcs-4878-446b-80e9-8d544860847a': 'test_table'}
QueryId of executed copy command

{'abcdcs-4878-446b-80e9-8d544860847a': 'test_table'}
Checking executed query status for each table.

test_table: Copy command failed

{'ClusterIdentifier': 'redshift-abc', 'CreatedAt': datetime.datetime(2022, 11, 10, 6, 21, 42, 363000, tzinfo=tzlocal()), 'Duration': -1, 'Error': 'ERROR: could not open relation with OID 591927', 'HasResultSet': False, 'Id': '9c6cb33c-4878-446b-80e9-8d544860847a', 'QueryString': " truncate table test_table;                     copy test_table                     from 's3://bucket_test/pipeline/test_table/year=2022/month=02/day=28/'                     iam_role ''                     delimiter as '\x01'                     ignoreheader 1                     dateformat as 'auto'                     timeformat as 'auto'                     Null as 'NULL';", 'RedshiftPid': 1073775000, 'RedshiftQueryId': 6553022, 'ResultRows': -1, 'ResultSize': -1, 'SecretArn': 'arn:aws:secretsmanager:abcd', 'Status': 'FAILED', 'UpdatedAt': datetime.datetime(2022, 11, 10, 6, 21, 42, 937000, tzinfo=tzlocal()), 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': 'c77cb319-14d3-42fd-8c34-611dbd5a17b4', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid': 'c77cb319-14d3-42fd-8c34-611dbd5a17b4', 'content-type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.1', 'content-length': '890', 'date': 'Thu, 10 Nov 2022 06:22:13 GMT'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}
Error occur in CheckQueryStatus block
ERROR: could not open relation with OID 591927
Error occur in main block.
Fail to refresh table in redshift.
{'MessageId': 'eb6338b8-cd1d-5d47-8a63-635e57fee266', 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': '60766afd-c861-5c1d-9d61-311b5282333c', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid': '60766afd-c861-5c1d-9d61-311b5282333c', 'content-type': 'text/xml', 'content-length': '294', 'date': 'Thu, 10 Nov 2022 06:22:26 GMT'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}
Email Notification sent to respective e-mail id.
ERROR: could not open relation with OID 591927
```

The error is raised from the CheckQueryStatus function, that is as follows:

```
## Check executed query status.
def CheckQueryStatus(QueryIdDict):
    InprogressQueryIdList = [key for key in QueryIdDict.keys()]
    SucceedTableList = []
   
   ## Expected Status of running query 
    FailStatus = ['ABORTED','FAILED']
    InprogressStatus = ['SUBMITTED','PICKED','STARTED']
    SucceedStatus = ['FINISHED']
    
    try:
        while len(InprogressQueryIdList):
            for QueryId in InprogressQueryIdList:
                response = client.describe_statement(
                    Id=QueryId
                )
                if response['Status'] in SucceedStatus:
                    SucceedTableList.append(QueryIdDict[QueryId])
                    InprogressQueryIdList.remove(QueryId)
                    print('Query Executed Sucessfully : ' + QueryIdDict[QueryId])
                    SourcePath = f's3://{BucketName}/pipeline/{QueryIdDict[QueryId]}/{PathPrefix}/'
                    DataDict= { 'Level': 'Info',
                                'SourceLocation': SourcePath,
                                'TargetDatabaseName': 'abc',
                                'TargetSchemaName': str(QueryIdDict[QueryId].split('.')[0]),
                                'TargetTableName': str(QueryIdDict[QueryId].split('.')[1]),
                                'ExecutedQuery': '',
                                'ExecutedQueryId': str(QueryId),
                                'Description': 'Data loaded successfully in staging table',
                                'Status': 'Succeed' 
                              }
                    DataList.append(DataDict)
                elif response['Status'] in InprogressStatus:
                    time.sleep(30)
                else:
                    print(QueryIdDict[QueryId] + ': Copy command failed\n')
                    print(response)
                    raise Exception(str(response['Error']))
                
        print('Table refreshed successfully\n')
        print(SucceedTableList)
    except Exception as e:
        SourcePath = f's3://{BucketName}/pipeline/{QueryIdDict[QueryId]}/{PathPrefix}/'
        DataDict= { 'Level': 'Error',
                    'SourceLocation': SourcePath,
                    'TargetDatabaseName': 'abc',
                    'TargetSchemaName': str(QueryIdDict[QueryId].split('.')[0]),
                    'TargetTableName': str(QueryIdDict[QueryId].split('.')[1]),
                    'ExecutedQuery': '',
                    'ExecutedQueryId': str(QueryId),
                    'Description': f'Copy command failed.{response["Error"]}',
                    'Status': 'Failed' 
                  }
        DataList.append(DataDict)
        print('Error occur in CheckQueryStatus block')
        print(e)
        raise
```

Now:

1. When I run the same copy command from DBeaver or some other query tool, it works perfectly fine.
2. When I run this code for other tables, exact same code, it works fine. Only failing for this table.
3. Created a test table to see if this is not the [typical Postgres OID bug](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20170518142443.29045.69550@wrigleys.postgresql.org), but the error could be replicated.

This has brought me to a state of confusion. Any help?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name in most of the places I see this is a Postgres issue/bug, Redshift is a PG based DWH. Hence I added the tag. Makes sense?

Comment: Redshift is not "Postgres based". Redshift has a totally different implementation and the COPY command as shown isn't even valid for Postgres.

Comment: Its based on PGSQL with differences like columnar storage, MPP, OLAP, etc. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_redshift-and-postgres-sql.html BTW, any help on the problem statement?

Comment: The whole storage layer and query execution is completely different implementation. Which is the core of a database engine and which makes it a completely different database. The "based on Postgres" is only marketing BS in my opinion. Sorry I have zero experience with Redshift.

Answer (score 0):

This error is often caused by stale table info and some other process that is dropping the target table (and possibly recreating a new table of the same name).  See similar questions / answers - [tracing the cause of "could not open relation with OID" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5030720/tracing-the-cause-of-could-not-open-relation-with-oid-error)

Comment: challenge is its strangely not happening with any other tables through the same code, nor is it happening with the same table when copy is run manually. Only through code. Also the copy table is working manually but not through code only for this table. What can be the steps to debug?