DBT Cloud scheduled job failing with error message "Database Error could not open relation with OID ******* "
I have created a scheduled job in dbt which loads the table with another table present in redshift with incremental strategy. Recently, I have started getting error while incrementally loading the table. The error message is like this:
"Database Error
could not open relation with OID 5978104"
I am not getting it every time but rather sometimes.
Can anyone help what might be the reason ?
I was expecting it to run normally like it is used to to load incremental data

related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5030720/tracing-the-cause-of-could-not-open-relation-with-oid-error
